# Bigquery is it possible to loop over list of values and apply functions

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is it possible to refactor this SQL ?

```
SELECT 
  field1,
  field2,
  contact 
FROM 
  `mytable` 
WHERE
  concat = CONCAT(
  (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 2 DAY))-1),"/",
  EXTRACT(WEEK(MONDAY) FROM DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)),"/",
  EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)))
  OR
  concat = CONCAT(
  (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 3 DAY))-1),"/",
  EXTRACT(WEEK(MONDAY) FROM DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)),"/",
  EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 3 DAY)))
  OR ...
  OR ...
  OR ... same function, just the INTERVAL value changes
```

I tried to see LOOPS in bigquery, GENERATE_ARRAY and other stuff but I can't reach my goal :(

Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
create temp function all_conditions(intervals int64) as (
  array(
    select concat(
      (extract(year from date_sub(current_date(), interval value day))-1),"/",
      extract(week(monday) from date_sub(current_date(), interval value day)),"/",
      extract(dayofweek from date_sub(current_date(), interval value day)))
    from unnest(generate_array(1, intervals)) value
  )
);
select 
  field1,
  field2,
  contact 
from `mytable`
where concat in unnest(all_conditions(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can wrap the OR you are using inside a loop. You could also try to use a user-defined function (UDF). Using a UDF would make it already a lot more readable and compact. Wrap your repeated SQL syntax in a function that would look something like this:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION extractInterval(x INT64) AS (
  CONCAT(
  (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL x DAY))-1),"/",
  EXTRACT(WEEK(MONDAY) FROM DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL x DAY)),"/",
  EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL x DAY)))
);
```

Then use that function in your query:

```
SELECT 
  field1,
  field2,
  contact 
FROM 
  `mytable` 
WHERE
  concat = extractInterval(2)
  OR
  concat = extractInterval(3)
  OR 
  ...
```

[Source](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY` to build your date range and join it in to your main query or use something like `where concat in (select ywd_string from date_range)`

```
with date_range as (
SELECT day as filler_date
  , CONCAT(
  (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Day)-1),"/",
  EXTRACT(WEEK(MONDAY) FROM day),"/",
  EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM day)) as ywd_string
FROM UNNEST(
    GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE('2020-06-20'), DATE('2020-09-19'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
) AS day
)
```